# ComboBox DisplayMemberPath containing LINQ group name and group elements inline

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, xaml

This is the object class:

```
 public class FileManagement
    {
        public string FileId { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public string TypeofFileName { get; set; }
    }
```

Then, I have a List of `FileManagement` objects and in my contructor I group the elements by `FileName` as follows

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, FileManagement>> GroupedList = FileList.GroupBy(p => p.FileName ).OrderBy(x => x.Key);
```

I am grouping them because there are more objects with the same `FileName` property, but with different `FileId` and `TypeofFileName`.

I have declared `IGrouping<string, FileManagement> SelectedFileType` that is set with the selected item of type `IGrouping<string, FileManagement>` in the first ComboBox from the XAML below.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding GroupedList }" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFileType}" >
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock.Text>
                            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}: {1}">
                                <Binding Path="Key"/>
                                <Binding Path="???some sort of string.Join"/>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </TextBlock.Text>
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedFileType}" DisplayMemberPath="TypeofFileName"></ComboBox>
```

The second ComboBox contains the `TypeofFileName` property of all the elements in the selected `IGrouping<string, FileManagement>` from first ComboBox. This is working as intended.

But I also want to set the following string as DisplayMemberPath for the first ComboBox:
"group_FileName:TypeofFileName1, TypeofFileName2, TypeofFileName3" where group_FileName is basically the key/group name, followed by the TypeofFileName property of all the elements in that group (like a `string.Join`).
Basically, I want to put in the DisplayMemberPath the group name and the group elements inline.

I am thinking about using MultiBinding and `string.Join(", ", SelectedFileType.ToList().Select(x => x.TypeofFileName))` but I do not know how to use it properly in binding.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Please use English member names in your code. XAML doesn't support something like `string.Join`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XAML doesn't support calling functions such as `string.Join` but you could bind to for example `SelectedObiectGeneral` and use a converter that calls `string.Join` and returns a `string`:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding>
            <MultiBinding.Converter>
                <local:YourConverter />
            </MultiBinding.Converter>
            <Binding Path="Key"/>
            <Binding Path="SelectedObiectGeneral"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

`YourConverter` is simply a class that implements either `IValueConverter` or `IMultiValueConverter` depending on whether you use a `Binding` or a `MultiBinding` in your XAML markup.

Comment: You have pointed me in the right direction, I have made a simple IValueConverter